# XPages: Erratic access to a 3rd database

Tags: xpages

I have a db, I'll call it db X, that contains all the XPages programming that accesses data in dbs A and B.  This is only used for web access, not in a Notes client.  One primary XPage in db X displays data from db A in a view (viewA) on one tab, and from db B (viewB) in another.  This works great!  However, when I click on a doc in viewA, it opens in another XPage just fine, and has a filtered version of viewB that is supposed to show just the docs from db B relevant to the current doc from db A.  But it is completely empty.  If I remove the filter, it should display all docs in db B, but is still empty.  I've verified that the data source for viewB is identical on both XPages.  Note that db A and db B are on the same server, and are even in the same folder.  Db X is on the same server as the other 2, but in a different folder (above the other 2).

Any ideas why viewB works in one XPage and not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your "embedded view" data source (viewB in docA) set the ignoreRequestParams property for the Domino view data source to true to ensure the view data source does not use the document ID that was present in the URL.

ADDITIONAL DETAILS:  In a two-page application involving a "view" XPage and a "document" XPage, when the application user clicks a link on the view page to open the document on the document page the ID for the document to open is passed with the REQUEST parameters.  You can see this in the resulting URL for the document page which will have the ID for the document to open appended to the URL address, for example &documentId=49530CA58D17CCE5852575150069D857&action=openDocument.  This works perfectly when the document page has only one Domino document data source.  However, in the embedded view application the "document" XPage will also include a data source for the xe:dataView.  When ignoreRequestParams is NOT true for the Domino view data source (and for any other additional data sources on the page) then the parameters passed in the request ARE evaluated to determine which view entries to display in the xe:dataView.  These request parameters point to a UNID that is not the desired data source for the view so no view entries are displayed.

Comment: Thank you, Paul!  I was certain I had already set the ignoreRequestParams to true, but took another look when you suggested it and sure enough, it was not set.  It is now, and viewB now shows up as it should.  Thanks again!